# OneNote 2016 - Lost Data During Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote-2016

I was on vacation for a week. When I returned, I did some kind of upgrade, either to Office 360 or Windows, didn't pay attention because it felt like a regular upgrade.  I discovered that my OneNote looked completely different than it ever has.  Also, I had to "reconnect" my notebooks to my OneDrive accounts.  The notebooks that appeared are over 18 months old.

Our best theory is that for 18 months I've been using onenote locally without syncing.  Somehow, when the sync finally started happening again, my local files were replaced with the 18-month old files from the cloud.  This seems impossible.  Why would MS allow an 18 month old file to replace one that was updated last week?  Alas, we cannot find the data anywhere.  For example, I had a tab titled "jeremy" and I cannot find the word Jeremy using a word search from Windows Explorer.

I saw a similar post where the speculation might be the user was running 2 versions of OneNote.  When I do a search on OneNo I only see 2016 on my computer.

Any recommendations are welcome!

Comment: I'm guessing what is more likely is that you've opened a different OneNote. There is a OneNote App built-in to Windows 10, and there is a OneNote program included with Office probably called OneNote 2016. Make sure you're opening the correct one.

Comment: “Why would MS allow an 18 month old file to replace one that was updated last week?” - Why wouldn’t this happen it was exactly what was allowed.  Microsoft can’t write software that reads your mind

Comment: I saw there were two One Note applications on my Windows 10 Laptop. All my notes are there in "One note for Windows 10". There is "One Note 2016" installed after the upgrade, still the old version can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Upgrade will not delete any personal data, unless user delete Windows.old folder manually or use disk cleanup tool.

Besides, OneNote automatically saves your notes, open File>Option>OneNote Options> Save & Backup, check your backup folder.

Finally, previous Windows version can be roll back via Setting>Update & Security >Recovery in 10 days.